# Providing implicit evidence for context bounds on Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, implicit

I'm trying to write some abstractions in some Spark Scala code, but running into some issues when using objects. I'm using Spark's `Encoder` which is used to convert case classes to database schema's here as an example, but I think this question goes for any [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/context-bounds.html#inner-main).

Here is a minimal code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
package com.sample.myexample

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

case class MySparkSchema(id: String, value: Double)

abstract class MyTrait[T: TypeTag: Encoder]

object MyObject extends MyTrait[MySparkSchema]
```

Which fails with the following compilation error:

```
Unable to find encoder for type com.sample.myexample.MySparkSchema. An implicit Encoder[com.sample.myexample.MySparkSchema] is needed to store com.sample.myexample.MySparkSchema instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I tried defining the implicit evidence in the object like such: (the import statement was suggested by IntelliJ, but it looks a bit weird)

```
import com.sample.myexample.MyObject.encoder

object MyObject extends MyTrait[MySparkSchema] {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[MySparkSchema] = Encoders.product[MySparkSchema]
}
```

Which fails with the error message

```
MyTrait.scala:13:25: super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name
```

One other thing I tried is to convert the object to a class and provide implicit evidence to the constructor:

```
class MyObject(implicit evidence: Encoder[MySparkSchema]) extends MyTrait[MySparkSchema]
```

This compiles and works fine, but at the expense of `MyObject` now being a `class` instead.

**Question: Is it possible to provide implicit evidence for the context bounds when extending a trait? Or does the implicit evidence force me to make a constructor and use `class` instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error almost gives you the solution, you have to import `spark.implicits._` for Product types.

You could do this:

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Full Example

```
package com.sample.myexample

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

case class MySparkSchema(id: String, value: Double)

abstract class MyTrait[T: TypeTag: Encoder]

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

object MyObject extends MyTrait[MySparkSchema]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! This does indeed provide the implicit evidence, but it doesn't compile directly like this, since I can't declare a val at toplevel. Removing the line with `com.sample.myexample` makes it compile, or wrapping it in a helper object also works, but both are not optimal

Comment: That's right, I've tested it inside an `Object`, sorry about that. You could put everything inside a `package object` (although it's being deprecated in Scala3) but I guess you still have the same problem, that you want to create the `object` at top-level.